# Access to request object in ASP.NET Core IFileProvider (Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a custom IFileProvider for RazorViewEngineOptions in a ASP.NET Core project. Is it possible to get access to the request object in GetFileInfo in the IFileProvider?

```
public class DBViewProvider : IFileProvider
{
    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
    {
        // access to Request here? 
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {               
            options.FileProviders.Add(new DBViewProvider());    
        });
}
```

There's only 1 global instance of the DBViewProvider so I'm unable to inject IHttpContextAccessor for every request.

Answer (score 0):

IHttpContextAccessor uses thread locals, you don't need to inject one per request.

Comment: Could you elaborate and/or provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing for now.

Created a helper class to hold a static IServiceProvider.

```
public static class MyServiceLocator
{   
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;

    public static void Init(IServiceProvider provider)
    {       
        ServiceProvider = provider; 
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs I initialize the ServiceProvider:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{    
    MyServiceLocator.Init(serviceProvider);
}
```

In my IFileProvider I get the IHttpContextAccessor:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; 

...

public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
{
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor = MyServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();         
}
```

Comment: You should be able to inject IHttpContextAccessor directly in Startup.Configure and pass it through, you shouldn't need to resolve a new one from the container per request.